# DIV's are not moving using getElementsByClassName()

Tags: javascript, html, css

I had started to create a game in HTML, CSS and JavaScript. I created a function that whenever I click on a button, all the red DIV's should start moving. However, I keep getting this error in the console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined. at index.html: 48

Due to this error, the DIV's don't move. I have used this code so far:

```js
function startGame() {
  var gameObj = document.getElementsByClassName("object");
  for (var i = 0; i < gameObj.length; i++) {
    var h = setInterval(function() {
      gameObj[i].style.transition = "1s";
      gameObj[i].style.left = Math.floor(Math.random() * 90) + "%";
      gameObj[i].style.top = Math.floor(Math.random() * 90) + "%";
    }, 500);
    document.getElementById("stop").addEventListener("click", function() {
      clearInterval(h);
    });
  }
}
```

```css
header {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10%;
  background-color: blue;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.object {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  transition: 1s;
  top: 40%;
  left: 30%;
}

.butn {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  border: none;
  height: 50%;
  width: 5%;
}
```

```html
<div class="object" id="object"></div>
<div class="object" style="top: 60%; left: 70%;"></div>
<header>
  <button onclick="startGame()" class="butn">Start</button>
  <button id="stop" class="butn">Stop</button>
</header>
```

When I used `getElementById` instead of `getElementsByClassName`, it worked. However, I can't use `getElementById()` since there are multiple DIV's. I am using the latest version of Chrome. Does anyone know that how can I fix it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move `setInterval()` at the root level of the `startGame()`

```js
function startGame() {
  var h = setInterval(function() {
    var gameObj = document.getElementsByClassName("object");
    for (var i = 0; i < gameObj.length; i++) {
      gameObj[i].style.transition = "1s";
      gameObj[i].style.left = Math.floor(Math.random() * 90) + "%";
      gameObj[i].style.top = Math.floor(Math.random() * 90) + "%";
    }
  }, 500);

  document.getElementById("stop").addEventListener("click", function() {
    clearInterval(h);
  });
}
```

```css
header {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10%;
  background-color: blue;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.object {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  transition: 1s;
  top: 40%;
  left: 30%;
}

.butn {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  border: none;
  height: 50%;
  width: 5%;
}
```

```html
<div class="object" id="object"></div>
<div class="object" style="top: 60%; left: 70%;"></div>
<header>
  <button onclick="startGame()" class="butn">Start</button>
  <button id="stop" class="butn">Stop</button>
</header>
```

Comment: Thankyou for your answer! It has solved my problem! However, could you please tell that why was it not working earlier?

Comment: that's because inside setInterval function, variable `i`  won't be working according to the variable function scope.

Comment: Ok. I am just a beginner at JavaScript, so I was not aware of this. Thankyou!

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you are using setInterval in the for loop.

There are two things happening here -

1. `setInterval` being asynchronous in nature takes the end value of `i` during execution, which would be `2`
2. `var` being a function-scoped variable is not retaining the value inside block-scoped for loop

To solve this you can wrap the setInterval in a function and pass the value of `i` as an argument. Like so -

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    header {
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      height: 10%;
      background-color: blue;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
    }
    
    .object {
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: red;
      transition: 1s;
      top: 40%;
      left: 30%;
    }
    
    .butn {
      cursor: pointer;
      color: white;
      background-color: black;
      border: none;
      height: 50%;
      width: 5%;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="object" id="object"></div>
  <div class="object" style="top: 60%; left: 70%;"></div>
  <header>
    <button onclick="startGame()" class="butn">Start</button>
    <button id="stop" class="butn">Stop</button>
  </header>
  <script>
  function moveElem(gameObj, i) {
    var h = setInterval(function() {
       gameObj[i].style.transition = "1s";
       gameObj[i].style.left = Math.floor(Math.random() * 90) + "%";
       gameObj[i].style.top = Math.floor(Math.random() * 90) + "%";
    }, 500);
    document.getElementById("stop").addEventListener("click", function() {
       clearInterval(h);
    });
  }

  function startGame() {
    var gameObj = document.getElementsByClassName("object");
    for (var i = 0; i < gameObj.length; i++) {
      moveElem(gameObj, i);
    }
  }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

This is a classic mistake you are bound to make when you are learning Javascript. The following articles will help you get a better understanding -

1. Closure - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures
2. Asynchronous - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous

Comment: Yeah that's the point. But seems `i` is going to be `2` instead of `3`. Since `i++` will let `i` becomes `0, 1, 2, EOL` (end of loop), but `setInterval` is asynchronous, so the whole code will becomes `gameObj[2]` which is undefined.

Comment: @CasimirCrystal My bad you are right, I thought I saw three divs, I will edit my answer

Comment: So, **Closure** is also a solution. Just change OP's code to `for (let i = 0)...` can still solving the problem. Which is gonna pass `gameObj[0]` and `gameObj[1]` to `setInterval` won't be a trouble in that case. @Shyamak Seth

Comment: Even though browsers nowadays support ES2015 and above, `let` can still cause compatibility issues for old browsers